# Finding windows of high-correlation across coordinates in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, ranking

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
id      start   end     score1  score2
[...]    
LmjF.31 280000  290000  .       .
LmjF.31 290000  300000  .       2686
LmjF.31 300000  310000  .       .
LmjF.31 310000  320000  .       74
LmjF.31 320000  330000  .       1897
LmjF.31 330000  340000  .       4116
LmjF.31 340000  350000  705     3156
LmjF.31 350000  360000  663     4145
LmjF.31 360000  370000  170     4864
[...]
LmjF.34 1140000 1150000 2284    2751
LmjF.34 1150000 1160000 .       .
LmjF.34 1160000 1170000 .       .
LmjF.34 1170000 1180000 572     .
[...]
```

(dot=`.` means score is 0)

I would like to rank the regions for each `id` where the correlation between score1 and score2 is highest . The second and third columns are `start` and `end` positions for sliding windows that at their minimum can be of size 1, but with smaller windows, fewer of them have non-zero on both scores, so I am already using bigger windows. Since these windows in different chromosomes for two different species, correlations in `score1` and `score2` that don't overlap but that are close to each other would still be relevant, but if they partially or fully overlap, then even better. That's why the sliding window size is relative, since I would like to use a method that takes into account cases like the ones for LmjF.31 start=340000 to end=370000, where there is three consecutive rows with a score bigger than 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: To get a good answer, please provide specific descriptions of what you mean by "window" and by "correlation."  You should also specify the sense in which "takes into account" is some modification of the usual definitions of correlation ([Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) and [Spearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), among others).

Comment: Given your comment to Gong-Yi Liao that the combination of id, start and end is the "window", the question does not make sense as written. Do you perhaps mean you want to rank the data according to how *close* score1 and score2 are in each row?  If so it is a pretty straightforward problem - just create a new variable that measures "closeness" (however you want to - proportional, absolute, or squared difference being the obvious choices) and rank on that basis.  But I suspect you want something else - you will probably need to edit the question rather thoroughly I'm afraid.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe now it's a bit clearer that this comes from already applying a sliding window on the raw data.

Comment: sorry, still don't understand - now you've introduced a new word "regions", what does that mean?  And I still don't understand what the correlation you are looking at is, nor what is meant by "taking into account" the situation near the end of your question.  Maybe have another go, giving an example of one subset of the data where column of score1 is correlated with an equal length column of score2.

Answer (score 1):

If "id" is your window id, than you may do :

```
rhos = NULL 
for w in unique(id)
    rhos = c(rhos, cor(data[data$id==w,c("score1", "score2")])[1,2])

rank = unique(id)[order(data)]
```

wish my assumption fits your data.

Comment: The window id is the combination of the first three columns: `id`, `start` and `end`.

Comment: Thus, each window has only one observation of score1 and score2. Therefore , a problem arises: how can one compute sample correlation with only one observation ?